# In TRIE implementation,what is efficient way to implement node?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, trie

I am using TRIE Data Structure for implementing dictionary, I am a bit confused as to which data type I should use when implementing TrieNode's children

Should I go with a node array of length 26

```
class TrieNode 
{ 
    TrieNode[] children = new TrieNode[ALPHABET_SIZE]; 

    // isEndOfWord is true if the node represents 
    // end of a word 
    boolean isEndOfWord; 

    TrieNode(){ 
        isEndOfWord = false; 
        for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) 
            children[i] = null; 
    } 
};
```

or should I go with **Hash Map** implementation

```
    class TrieNode{
    char value;
    boolean isEnd;
    Map<Character,TrieNode> children;

    public TrieNode(char value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Which one is more efficient and will consume less memory?

Comment: efficiency in terms of computation? If yes, It will depend on what what Map implementation you are using. In arrays you will get absolute constant time element access, but in `TreeMap` it will depend on the number of elements you have specifically `O(log(n))` (number of elements in map in your case will be `ALPHABET_SIZE` at max). And going with `HashMap` will solve this problem. And with Arrays you might be wasting memory - but that too will be very small.

Comment: I don't think that this is even a space time trade-off question. I think you should always go with arrays. Because with `Map` you don't get benefit in any field - neither space, not time. Arrays always win in time, so no doubt there. It might be intimidating to go for `Map` to save memory, but the objects will themselves be very heavy that they will overpower the memory "wasted" by array-implementation